# How to avoid too many ops from a loop in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

** **Edition**:  to avoid ambiguity,  my problem is "too many" ops, "a large number" of ops. Not about the numerical value of a certain op.

> My Old Title: How to avoid a large number of ops from a loop in
> tensorflow?

** Following is the main text

Hi, Guys. I'm using tensorflow 1.12 to implement a network.

### The background is:

In my loss function, I want to compute a large number (about 5000) of random point pairs that sampled from every input image, which costs me a lot of memory and time. The subscripts of point pairs are chosen by a certain method with randomness, so I think it's impossible to integrate the loop into a matrix. It appears like this: ( in `my_loss_func()` )

```
# gt & pred is tensors of [w, h]
# x1, y1, x2, y2 are lists of the point pairs' coordinates which were randomly sampled from input image
# for example, x1 = [1, 2, 3], y1 = [4, 5, 6], x2 = [7, 8, 9], y2 = [10, 11, 12]
# then it will compute loss between gt[1, 4] & pred[7, 10], gt[2, 5] & pred[8, 11] etc.

num_pairs = 5000
...

# compute loss for this batch
for i in range(num_pairs):
   diff = gt[x1[i], y1[i]] - pred[x2[i], y2[i]]
   loss = some_math_computation(diff)

return loss/num_pairs
```

### The problem is:

If I build the graph like above, it will definitely create the loss computing op for 5k times, which costs me a lot. In fact, every time I run the program, I must wait for about 10 mins before the first batch of data's getting trained. In my DEBUG log, I found that the loop runs for only about 25 times within a second. Thus the large time cost is definitely from here. I feel myself so nooob.

Can you tell me how to avoid building the graph like this? Btw, I'm using `tf.estimator`, so the `sess.run()` operation is invalid.

### My opinions:

Maybe I can load the total graph for once, and save this graph as file. Then for every time I run the model, I can load the total graph from that file, so I won't need to wait such a long time. Will it work?

Please tell me the correct way to implement this kind of loss. I think maybe this kind of loss is quite common in some fields of computer vision.

Comment: Look for log loss in tensorflow.

Comment: sry, did you mean losses.log_loss? Could you please tell more detail about it, thank you very much:)

Comment: Used to avoid extremely large or small gradients. Take a look at the docs for more.

Comment: Sorry, I think maybe my expression is kind of ambigous. The problem has nothing to do with gradients. I'm not meeting a large NUMBER in loss, but a LOT of ops which occupied my memory. The problem is I have too many ops created by the loop, and I don't know if I can avoid creating such many ops. The numerical value of each op and gradient has no problem. Do you have some solution to this porblem? or have I misunderstood you?